# Is there a way to always use Optional-chaining in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working with an Angular app where the api response can be missing some expected data.

This can crash the app and an easy fix has been to use Optional-chaining;

foo.bar.baz => foo.bar?.baz

Is there a setting or way to treat all '.' as '?.' and would this be a bad idea for any reason?

Comment: In case you can't rely on the presence of certain props returned by the API (especially when it's a third-party API), it's definitly a good idea to avoid 'undefined'-errors - but I wouldn't know of any such _setting_, Rick & Morty need to implement optional chainging themselvees where needed when handling the repsonses..

Comment: Do you have TypeScript with strict null checks enabled? The compiler should be catching these mistakes for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i went through the official Angular & Typescript docs, There is no such option.
And there shouldn't be.

Its definitely a bad idea.
This will result in "Silent" bugs, that will be hard to find as the system grows.

e.g. if you have the following model:

```
interface ContactInfoDTO {
   email: string;
   phone: string;
}

interface UserDTO {
   name: string;
   contactInfo: ContactInfoDTO;
}
```

And you assume that every user in the system should have a valid contact info.
When you access the email property user?.contactInfo?.email, you could end up with a bug, not knowing that something is actually wrong with your data, since no error was thrown.

**Use Optional-chaining carefully, only where you know that some data might not be defined for a reason.**

There is a nice article on the matter:
https://medium.com/@a.hafez852/is-optional-chaining-really-a-good-addition-to-javascript-e4bbbc31909f